# Serializing TypeInfo / Type across .Net Platforms

Tags: c#, serialization, reflection, windows-store-apps, portable-class-library

I'm in the process of porting a regular .Net 4.5 library over to the Portable Class Library profile 111 - which includes Windows Store, Windows Phone, Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOS and Desktop. Part of that framework is a **custom serialization system** to deal with some of the limitations from the .Net ones.

**Data will be serialized across platforms**, meaning that I might serialize an object running in .Net 4.5 on Desktop and deserialize it in a Windows Store app. This fact combined with the [Evolved Reflection API](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2012/08/28/evolving-the-reflection-api.aspx) creates an unfortunate serialization **problem with Type and TypeInfo**.

In normal operation, the serializer asks an object for its type using `GetType` and decides how to proceed based on that. If it turns out to be a reference to a `Type`, a string ID will be serialized that can be used for resolving the `Type` during deserialization, other cases are handled differently. As the serializer also handles metadata about each serialized object, you will never need to tell it what kind of object you expect, but instead will receive a fully deserialized object as is.

The problem arises from the fact that, in .Net 4.5 at runtime, `GetType()` on a `Type` reference will return `RuntimeType`, which derives from `TypeInfo`, which derives from `Type`, `MemberInfo` and so on.. so when running in .Net 4.5, the object will be *both* `Type` and `TypeInfo`. Neither does it matter, **nor is it possible to distinguish between them**.

[image: Inheritance tree in .Net 4.5 vs. Windows Store]

*However*, this is not the case when deserializing the data stream in a Windows Store app, where `Type` and `TypeInfo` are completely distinct classes. Which one should be retrieved when resolving the string ID? `Type` or `TypeInfo`?

The reason it matters is that both users and the serializer itself always expect to deserialize the same kind of object that was previously serialized, but because `Type` and `TypeInfo` cannot be distinguished in .Net 4.5, **this information is missing** during deserialization in a Windows Store app. Making a choice in favor of one of those types will cause errors when the other would have been expected, and there is no way to predict which one is expected.

Is there any way to solve this?

So far, I've been considering various options, like scattering a lot of "implicit cast"-like checks and conversions throughout the serializer code, but this doesn't really cover all cases and especially not the ones involving unsuspecting users who will get an object of the wrong type.. any advice or experience on this would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Strongly recommend using `protcol buffers`, `servicestack`, or something along those lines so that this all becomes platform-agnostic.

Comment: How would using a library solve the somewhat "fundamental" problem that I'm facing? If they can solve it, I need to know how, in order to fix my own stuff - switching serialization systems entirely is not a viable option.

Comment: `Protocol buffers` and the like make serialization platform-agnostic. The payload would be a stream of bytes, which then are deserialized into known types by the receiving end. The contracts to (automatically) generate the types are handled by `protobuf` compilers (Jon Skeet wrote one version, Marc Gravell wrote the other, for .NET) which adhere to the protobuf standards.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at how [LightInject](https://github.com/seesharper/LightInject/blob/master/LightInject.Source/LightInject.cs) handles this scenario using conditional compilation.